# Preencher um Dropdown (Select)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso criar um select Neste padrão:

```
<select id="Cidades">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Onde o usuário selecionará o estado dele, e então será feito um jquery que busca as cidades de acordo com o estado selecionado. até aqui eu consigo fazer (mas ainda não fiz), o meu problema é como faria para enviar os dados de retorno de json para o dropdown (Select), e queria saber se o select a cima também está correto para preencher os dados.

Comment: você já fez uma pergunta muito parecida com essa semana passada, eu fiz um update na [minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/166323/30045) vê se não te ajuda. Ai pode remover essa pergunta =]

Comment: pois é @Brunno kkk mas como o escopo deu uma mudada, preferi fazer uma nova pergunta, até mesmo pq já tentei fazer outra pergunta em cima de uma pergutna e me criticaram rsrsrs. mas obrigado. quando chegar em casa eu vejo ;) Valeu Mesmo. Ah se tu puder me ajudar nesta outra [Pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/166981/erro-em-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $.ajax({
        type: ...,
        url: ...,
        datatype: "Json",
        data: { ... },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#Cidades').append('<option value="' + value.Id+ '">' + value.Nome + '</option>');
                });
            } else {
                var novaOpcao = $('<option value=""></option>');
                $('#Cidades').append(newOption);
            }
        }
    });
```

O retorno entra no callback **success**.
Ele utiliza um loop para cada cidade retornada em Json. Coloquei como **value.Id** e **value.Nome** para referenciar as propriedades da entidade Cidade, mas se for outro é só ajustar.

O "else" força uma opção nula caso não existam cidades cadastradas para aquele Estado, daí facilita a validação pelo menos do front-end caso você tenha definido isso.

Comment: Funcionou, porém se eu clicar mais de uma vez no botão, ele preenche com os dados duplicando tudo. acredito que teria que limpar esta lista primeiro, antes de adicionar novamente. Sabe como posso fazer?